# Typescript server side, class not work

Tags: typescript

When I execute node server-file.ts, receive then receives

```
name: string;
    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

This is my code

```
"use strict";

class ChatClient {
    name: string;
    surname: string;
    text_color: string;
    constructor(name: string, surname: string, text_color: string) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.text_color = text_color; 
    }
};
```

Comment: node js executes ".js" files only. you should transpile "ts" to "js" using typescript compiler (https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-compiler)

Comment: Try it [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground) gives no error

Answer (score 2):

You need to compile first... simplistically you could use:

```
tsc --module umd server-file.ts
```

This will generate the `server.file.js` file that you can run happily on Node.

You can also simplify your class as per the below ([stop manually mapping your constructor parameters](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2013/04/stop-manually-assigning-typescript-constructor-parameters/)).

```
"use strict";

class ChatClient {
    constructor(public name: string, public surname: string, public text_color: string) {

    }
};
```